# jquery mobile splash screen and hiding of Safari toolbars

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, splash-screen

Does jQuery Mobile support splash screen for e.g. iPhone and iPad? I reckon this should be a .png with a specific name placed on root?

Also: is there a way to hide Safari toolbars (url/footer) when a web-app is placed on desktop/home screen? jQTouch does this, but this does not work out of the box in jQuery Mobile.

Thanks!

Comment: When it comes to the splash screen part of the question use the following link-tags for homescreen icon and splash screen:
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="desktopicon.png" />

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions isn't really related to jQuery Mobile.

To hide the url and footer you must enable web app mode on your mobile web site and add it to the homescreen, i.e. install it.

Just add the following meta tag as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

To make it more obvious for your visitors that they have to install your web app you can add the [Google Mobile Bookmark Bubble](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/).

The splash screen can be added with the apple-touch-startup-image meta tag as you commented your self.

However, be aware that web app mode totally disables multitasking, i.e. makes your site/web app reload each time the user choses it from the running apps, and that might not be acceptable for you.